# How does the following shell script work in finding all files larger than 20MB?

Tags: shell-script, awk

I came across a post advising that the following will find all files greater than 20Mb in size.

```
find / -type f -size +20000k -exec ls -lh {} \; 2> /dev/null   | awk '{ print $NF ": " $5 }'  | sort -hrk 2,2
```

It seems to work but I don't understand what its doing after the '+20000k' .

Comment: excellent site to understand onliner  => [ExplainShell.com](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+%2F+-type+f+-size+%2B20000k+-exec+ls+-lh+{}+\%3B+2%3E+%2Fdev%2Fnull+++|+awk+%27{+print+%24NF+%22%3A+%22+%245+}%27++|+sort+-hrk+2%2C2)

Answer (score 6):

```
find / -type f -size +20000k -exec ls -lh {} \; 2> /dev/null   | awk '{ print $NF ": " $5 }'  | sort -hrk 2,2
```

- `/`: find starts in main directory
- `-type f`: find only regular files
- `-size +20000k`: with size 20000k or more
- `-exec ls -lh {} \;`: for each file which has been found execute `ls -lh`, i.e. list them in long format and human readable size (with suffix 'K', 'M', 'G', etc.)
- `2>/dev/null`: if `find` generated any error messages redirect them to the black hole
- `|`: pipe the `find` result to the next command (awk in this case)
- `awk '{print $NF ": " $5}'`: print the last field (of the `ls -lh` output) followed by colon and then followed by fifth field. The last field is file name, and the fifth field is size of the file (in human readable format as mentioned before).
- `|`: again pipe the result (this time from `awk` to `sort`)
- `sort -hrk 2,2`: sort result by human readable numbers in reverse order taking into account only second field.

---

**Note**

You can do this task much simpler and faster without `awk` and `sort` commands:

```
find / -type f -size +20000k -exec ls -Shs {} +
```

where

- `ls -Shs`: list files, print their sizes in human readable format and at the same time sort them by size
- `{} +` add files found by `find` to the list, and only at the end perform `ls` on the whole list. In `{} \;` case `ls` runs on each file separately.

The only difference between these two commands is that in former case size in printed on second column, while in latter on first. However if files or directories have spaces in names then output of `ls -l` has different number of columns for each file, so the output of `awk` will be more or less random. In other words [you should not parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 4):

The

```
-exec ls -lh {} \;
```

makes find execute the command `ls -lh` on each file found `{}`, and '`\;`' indicates that each file is handed to the command separately. From the man page:

```
   -exec command ;
          Execute command; true if 0 status is returned.   All  following
          arguments  to  find  are  taken  to be arguments to the command
          until an argument consisting of `;' is encountered.  The string
          `{}'  is  replaced  by  the  current  file name being processed
          everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, not  just
          in  arguments  where  it is alone, as in some versions of find.
          Both of these constructions might need to be  escaped  (with  a
          `\')  or  quoted  to  protect them from expansion by the shell.
          See the EXAMPLES section for examples of the use of  the  -exec
          option.   The  specified  command  is run once for each matched
          file.  The command  is  executed  in  the  starting  directory.
          There  are unavoidable security problems surrounding use of the
          -exec action; you should use the -execdir option instead.
```

The `2> /dev/null` part makes sure that errors, e.g. for directories that are not readable, get thrown away (`/dev/null`).

The actual output of `ls -lh` for one file looks like:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 anthon users   1,2K Aug 24  2013 sizes.data1
```

and that goes into the `awk` command which extracts the name of the file (NF for the number of fields) and 5th field from that (for the example: `sizes.data1: 1.2K`)

Those name: size combinations get piped into `sort` which sorts on the second field (`-k 2,2`). The -h for sort matches the -h output from `ls -lh`, the `-r` reverse sorts.

Answer (score 2):

> -exec ls -lh {} \; 2> /dev/null

For every file bigger than 20MB runs ls command with -l and -h options and redirects errors to /dev/null.

> ```
>     -l     use a long listing format
>
>     -h, --human-readable
>           with -l, print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
> ```

This creates an output like:

> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 58M Oct 15  2012 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar

Awk command:

> awk '{ print $NF ": " $5 }'

prints file name with its size, $NF means last column and $5 means fifth column:

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar: 58M

And last command:

> sort -hrk 2,2

sorts second column, which is size, in reverse:

> ```
>    -h, --human-numeric-sort
>           compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)
>    -r, --reverse
>           reverse the result of comparisons
>    -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
>           start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You may simplify this by find's -printf:

```
find . -type f -size +20k -printf "%h/%f: %kk\n" | sort -hrk 2,2
```

But read the manpage of find about the subtilities between %s and %k. (I refused to search from / and used for testing ., and reduced the size to +20k, instead of +20M to find anything in .